# Using a multiple select in a Linq-to-SQL expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, sqlgeography

I need to call a model + object in my table in view .. how can I add the variable `TotalTime` and insert it in my table?

This is my code :

```
schoolinfo az = new schoolinfo();

var durer = 3;
var EstimationPrep = 20;

var  TotalTime = durer * az.Location.Distance(point) + EstimationPrep;

var places = (from u in context.schoolinfo 
              orderby u.Location.Distance(point)
              where u.Location.Distance(point) < DistanceMax
              select u).Take(10);
var nearschools = places.ToList();

return View(nearschools);
```

Thanks

Comment: Insert where? as a new column? in all the rows the same value? [edit] your question and please make it clearer

Comment: me neither understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: i need just add a new row for each element in my modal view

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear but if you just want to add TotalTime to every row in places you can do that like this:

```
var places = (from u in context.schoolinfo 
          orderby u.Location.Distance(point)
          where u.Location.Distance(point) < DistanceMax
          select new { u.column1, TotalTime }).Take(10);
```